# MySQL Better Pivot Code?

Tags: mysql, pivot, union, frequency

So I have table like this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B1
```

I know how to output the top 5 numbers in A1-A5 with:

```
SELECT n,
COUNT(*) as `freq`
FROM (
    SELECT `A1` as `n FROM `tbl`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `A2` FROM `tbl`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `A3` FROM `tbl`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `A4` FROM `tbl`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `A5` FROM `tbl`) AS x
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

But I need to pivot that data to output the top 5 occurrences of A1-A5 into like x1(1st most), x2(2nd most), x3(3rd most), x4(4th most), x5(5th most) and add the top occurrence of B1 as the last column.

Now Here's what I came up with that "works", but it's slow (Like more than 20 minutes slow)!

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT x1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `a1` AS `x1` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a5` FROM `tbl`

    ) as transposed
    GROUP BY x1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as x1,
(
    SELECT x2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `a1` AS `x2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a5` FROM `tbl`

    ) as transposed
    WHERE x2 NOT IN (x1)
    GROUP BY x2
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as x2,
(
    SELECT x3
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `a1` AS `x3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a5` FROM `tbl`

    ) as transposed
    WHERE x3 NOT IN (x1, x2)
    GROUP BY x3
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as x3,
(
    SELECT x4
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `a1` AS `x4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a5` FROM `tbl`

    ) as transposed
    WHERE x4 NOT IN (x1, x2, x3)
    GROUP BY x4
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as x4,
(
    SELECT x5
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `a1` AS `x5` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a2` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a3` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a4` FROM `tbl`

        UNION ALL
        SELECT `a5` FROM `tbl`

    ) as transposed
    WHERE x5 NOT IN (x1, x2, x3, x4)
    GROUP BY b5
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
    DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) as x5,
(
    SELECT `b1` FROM `tbl`
    GROUP BY b1
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    DESC
    LIMIT 1
) as b1;
```

Any ideas on how to improve this monster of a query?!?!

Comment: Can you show sample data and your expected output?  Note that MySQL does not support row number, but it can be simulated using session variables if needed.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: OK so each row, A1-A5 will contain a number between 1 and 75, but A1-A5 will not repeat any number in that row, so you can have: 

`code
    1, 34, 54, 23, 12, 6
` for A1-15 B1 will be a number 1-15 code So data table could look like this 
`code
    1, 34, 54, 23, 12, 6, 
    1 2,34,5,12,1, 2`
 Output should be like:
`code
   x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, b1 32, 2, 12, 15, 1, 12`